# How to move map after marker was selected

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I want to create animation: after click on marker, center of map should move to that marker and verticaly to a fixed point from bottom (I have some semi-transparent views on top and bottom of a map and want always to see whole callout after marker was clicked). How to acheve that? I saw I can move map to region and to map coordinate, but is it possible to move to point on screen?

Comment: any update on this question?

Comment: Hi! Nope, I was not able to create such a thing (and noone replied) so I dropped this idea.

Comment: Its working normally on Physical device. Not working on emulator.